# Pyramid: Multi-threaded Database Operation

Tags: python, multithreading, pyramid

My application receives one or more URLs (typically 3-4 URLs) from the user, scrapes certain data from those URLs and writes those data to the database. However, because scraping those data take a little while, I was thinking of running each of those scraping in a separate thread so that the scraping + writing to the database can keep on going in the background so that the user does not have to keep on waiting.

To implement that, I have (relevant parts only):

```
@view_config(route_name="add_movie", renderer="templates/add_movie.jinja2")
def add_movie(request):
    post_data = request.POST

    if "movies" in post_data:
        movies = post_data["movies"].split(os.linesep)

        for movie_id in movies:        
            movie_thread = Thread(target=store_movie_details, args=(movie_id,))
            movie_thread.start()

    return {}

def store_movie_details(movie_id):

    movie_details = scrape_data(movie_id)
    new_movie = Movie(**movie_details) # Movie is my model.

    print new_movie  # Works fine.

    print DBSession.add(movies(**movie_details))  # Returns None.
```

While the line `new_movie` does print correct scrapped data, `DBSession.add()` doesn't work. In fact, it just returns `None`.

If I remove the threads and just call the method `store_movie_details()`, it works fine.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the SA docs on [Session.add()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session) do not mention anything about the method's return value, so I would assume it is expected to return `None`.

Secondly, I think you meant to add `new_movie` to the session, not `movies(**movie_details)`, whatever that is :)

Thirdly, the standard Pyramid session (the one configured with ZopeTransactionExtension) is tied to Pyramid's request-response cycle, which may produce unexpected behavior in your situation. You need to configure a separate session which you will need to commit manually in `store_movie_details`. This session needs to use [scoped_session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions) so the session object is thread-local and is not shared across threads.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
AsyncSession = scoped_session(session_factory)

def store_movie_details(movie_id):

    session = AsyncSession()
    movie_details = scrape_data(movie_id)
    new_movie = Movie(**movie_details) # Movie is my model.

    session.add(new_movie)
    session.commit()
```

And, of course, this approach is only suitable for very light-weight tasks, and if you don't mind occasionally losing a task (when the webserver restarts, for example). For anything more serious have a look at Celery etc. as Antoine Leclair suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction manager closes the transaction when the response is returned. DBSession has no transaction in the other threads when the response has been returned. Also, it's probably not a good idea to share a transaction across threads.

This is a typical use case for a worker. Check out [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) or [RQ](http://python-rq.org).