# pyramid threading not working

Tags: python, multithreading, titan

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor,as_completed
from rexpro import RexProConnection
query="g.V('node_type','x').count()"

future=[]
conns=[ RexProConnection('localhost', 8184, 'graph') for each in range(30)]
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=40) as executor:
    for each in range(30):
    future.append(executor.submit(conns[each].execute,query))
count=0
for f in as_completed(future):
    count=count+f.result()    
    print "count="+str(count)
```

I am trying to optimize one of our APIs where we are making multiple calls to titan database.I have tried little test with sequential version and the one using future like mentioned above, and test shows that if we use future it performs 50% well than the sequential counterpart, but the problem is when I integrate the code with pyramid framework, it does not show any performance improvement, it seems like some pyramid issue to me.I really appreciate your help.

Comment: have you seen this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705323/pyramid-multi-threaded-database-operation

Comment: Are you deploying on top of uWsgi?

Comment: I am deploying with wsgi